# How to filter matrix by row subtotals in Power BI?

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax

I have a matrix that shows flight data and travellers names, with totals to show how many passengers are on each flight. I need to be able to filter this table down by the row totals so that only those with 2+ travellers are shown, but I cannot figure out how to do so since the count will always show as 1 for each line.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the calculated table provides the expected results, it won't inherit filter context from the visual so this solution. Best solution is below.

```
Passenger Per Flight Filter = 
IF(
   [Passenger per Flight] <> BLANK(),
   CALCULATE( [Passenger per Flight], ALL( 'Dim Traveller' ) ),
   BLANK()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a matrix visual and show the count of travelers, it is essentially an implied measure. You can't place a measure in a filter because the calculation will vary depending on the context of the visual.

You can [create a calculated table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables) that summarizes the flight data. You can then use the "Travelers" field from this new table in a numeric filter.

```
Summary Table = SUMMARIZE(Flights,Flights[Flight Number], "Travelers", Count(Flights[Traveler]))
```

[image: result]